# How to find which version of Font Awesome is on this page?

Tags: vaadin, font-awesome

I have to modify a legacy application and I want to quickly figure out what version of Font-Awesome the application is running, so I know which icons are available.

I ran Chrome Inspect and saw it's using FontAwesome.We are working on vaadin project

[image]

Comment: Download the font and have a look with e.g. font-forge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Vaadin you are using? FontAwesome was the stock icon font in Vaadin 7, and it was replaced with our own icon font set in Vaadin 8. If you are not using Vaadin 8 with FontAwesome added to your application yourself, but Vaadin 7, then it is probably version 4.2.0, as it was the last one update there, and has not been updated after that.